# Enviar Botão Adicionar ao Calendário com PHPMailer

Tags: google, phpmailer

Tenho esse script.

```
<!-- AddEvent -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://addevent.com/libs/atc/1.6.1/atc.min.js" async defer></script>

<div title="Add to Calendar" class="addeventatc">
    Add to Calendar
    <span class="start">05/30/2017 16:00</span>
    <span class="end">05/30/2017 18:00</span>
    <span class="timezone">America/Caracas</span>
    <span class="title">Summary of the event</span>
    <span class="description">Description of the event</span>
    <span class="location">Location of the event</span>
    <span class="date_format">MM/DD/YYYY</span>
    <span class="client">apjeYlqFLzfsSVnNdmRH28418</span>
</div>
```

Segundo o tutorial [dessa](https://www.addevent.com/buttons/add-to-calendar) pagina

Gostaria de enviar o botão "Adicionar Ao Calendário" usando o [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

Só que não consegui adicionar o javascript na mensagem

Mesmo setando a linha

```
$mail->IsHTML(true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você manda um email, automaticamente o Cliente de Email, bloqueia qualquer script que venha a ser incluído no corpo do e-mail.

Ou seja não vai ter como você adicionar o Widget do addevent no corpo do email.

Sugiro você dar uma olhada na API da própria addevent e checar se existe a possibilidade de você utilizar os serviços deles, ai você apenas iria criar um link simples no corpo do email, que redirecionaria para esta página que será incumbida de dar continuidade ao registro dos eventos.